# Arithmetic modulo $n$ when $n>a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$r=a \pmod n$ can be rewritten as $a = qn + r$ where $a$ and $n$ are positive and non-zero integers and $q$ is a unique integer.
When solving for $a \pmod n$ such that $a$ is greater than $n$, it is straight forward. But what happens when $n$ is greater than $a$?
For instance, $10\pmod{15} =10$ but why?

Comment: I mentioned n greater than a.

Comment: That is the case $q = 0$.

Comment: I assume you mean when n is greater than a? Then $q=0$ and $r = a$. i.e. $a=0\times q +a$.

Comment: @user no you said $n>n$ but obviously that was a typo. I've fixed it. Also, $a$ can be *any* integer including $0$ and negative numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $a = 0\cdot n+a$, so $q=0$, $r=a$ works if $0\le a<n$.